# Find index of loop iteration

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want change icon background color in my GridView item, trying like this

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    childAspectRatio: 0.85,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(15, (index) {
        if (index % 8 == 1 || index % 8 == 2) {
            changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(255, 173, 49, 0.26);
        }
        if (index % 8 == 3 || index % 8 == 5) {
            changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(46, 209, 180, 0.26);
        }
        if (index % 8 == 4 || index % 8 == 6) {
            changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 198, 255, 0.26);
        }
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CategoryRoute()), );
            },
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Stack(
                    children: < Widget > [
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 7),
                                ],
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                child: Text(
                                    categoryName[index % categoryName.length],
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: const Color(0xFF71768D),
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            )
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            left: 0.0,
                            right: 0.0,
                            child: MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                disabledColor: changeColor,
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    iconList[index % iconList.length],
                                    width: 40,
                                    height: 40,
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                shape: CircleBorder(),
                            )
                        ),
                    ]
                )
            )
        );
    })
),
```

Default value of changeColor: var changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26);
I am trying to do something similar to my css:

```
.categories-item:nth-child(8n):before, .categories-item:nth-child(8n + 2):before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 173, 49, 0.26);
}

.categories-item:nth-child(8n + 3):before, .categories-item:nth-child(8n + 5):before {
  background-color: rgba(46, 209, 180, 0.26);
}

.categories-item:nth-child(8n + 4):before, .categories-item:nth-child(8n + 6):before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 198, 255, 0.26);
}

.categories-item:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 87, 255, 0.26);
}
```

It works but not like in the css: if (index % 8 == 1 || index % 8 == 2) {}, how else can this be done? Any ideas please

Comment: The CSS uses `8n` and `8n + 2`, but the corresponding Dart code uses `index % 8 == 1 || index % 8 == 2`.  Why did you use `index % 8 == 1` instead of `index % 8 == 0`?

Comment: index % 8 == 0 is it ignored, dont know why

Comment: That should not be possible.  If your other offsets are working, then there's no reason why `index % 8 == 0` shouldn't.

Comment: First element color Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26), with index % 8 == 0 is Color.fromRGBO(255, 173, 49, 0.26)

Comment: Maybe you need to change the default color value again in cases where the color does not fall under the rule?

Comment: It might help to make `changeColor` variable local to the anonymous function you pass to `List.generate`.

Comment: Can i have an example?

Comment: Try doing `List.generate(15, (index) { var changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26); if (index == ...`.  It's otherwise harder to reason about `changeColor` when it's not a local variable and retains its previous value across iterations.

Comment: Same problem(((

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `changeColor` inside `setState(() {})` then only there will be a change in the Flutter UI. You need to do it like this:

```
    if (index % 8 == 0) {
        setState((){
           changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26);
        });
    }
    if (index % 8 == 1 || index % 8 == 2) {
        setState((){
           changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(255, 173, 49, 0.26);
        });
    }
    if (index % 8 == 3 || index % 8 == 5) {
        setState((){
           changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(46, 209, 180, 0.26);
        });
    }
    if (index % 8 == 4 || index % 8 == 6) {
        setState((){
           changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 198, 255, 0.26);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand why this is happening, but 3 color should be Color.fromRGBO(46, 209, 180, 0.26), but he Color.fromRGBO(255, 173, 49, 0.26);

Comment: default changeColor value Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26) ignored

Comment: @Elexer I think, the problem here is that after using setState the changeColor changes temporarily until App restarts or reloads. To solve this problem you also need to provide the color for the index number 0. See the edited answer for the final code.

Comment: i have default value in my HomePageState `var changeColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26);`

Comment: @Elexer yeah but it will change whenever the index is not 0 or multiple of 8. To make sure that you have the same color  `Color.fromRGBO(0, 87, 255, 0.26)`, you need to justify the color for every index.

Comment: Did i understand correctly that it is unrealistic to do it like in CSS?

Comment: @Elexer You also need to mention the color for every index in CSS.